# animate() on hover affecting underlying link

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I am creating an effect where I hover over an image and the opacity fades to reveal underlying links to other parts of the webpage.

Here is the jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#columnRight,#columnRight2,#columnRight3,#columnRight4").hover(function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0.2"}, 'slow');
   },
   function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'slow');
   });
});
```

It targets the following HTML:

```
<div id="columnRight">
    <a href="syllabus.html">syllabus</a>
</div>
```

& CSS:

```
  #columnRight {
    width: 735px;
    height: 205px;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
    float: left; 
    background: url('images/books.jpg');    
}
```

The effect works great except for two things:

> 1. The link is visible through the image before any animation happens. I would like it to be invisible before the hover effect.
> 2. The link is inheriting the animation effect, so as I hover over the image, the link fades with the background image.

I have been working over a couple possible solutions, but thought I would ask before getting too far into either of them:

> 1. Create another div that contains the links and position it underneath the div with the background image. That way when I `.hover`, it will reveal the links from below.
> 2. Write another script that fades in the link as the image fades out.

Comment: I suggest using `.fadeTo()` in place of animate if you are just changing opacity. Animating the property opacity, does just that, it manipulates only the opacity property which it not supported IE<9. `.fadeTo()` will take care of cross browser fading. 

Secondly, you've provide no styling for your anchor so it's hard to understand what you mean by "link is visible".

Comment: You should set the z-index of the image to 1000 or something to have it overlay the links, then on hover change the z-index to -1 to have it drop behind the links, then they will become visible. Think of it as a pop-up box in reverse.

Comment: @Rob Thx for the comment. The anchor is styled font-size: 30px and it's black. Basically the anchor can be seen through the image when I want it to be below the image.

Comment: Also, will .fadeTo() will work with @Laurence's solution below?

Comment: Yes, here is a new fiddle with .fadeTo(): http://jsfiddle.net/2akwx/1/

Comment: Thx. Why was zIndex changed to z-index when using .fadeTo()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use z-index and absolute positioning to get this to work.
Here is a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HMxdt/10/

```
$("#container").hover(function() {
   $(this).find(".overlay").stop().animate({opacity: "0.2", zIndex:"-1"}, 'fast');
   },
   function() {
  $(this).find(".overlay").stop().animate({opacity: "1", zIndex:"1000"}, 'fast');
});
```

With .fadeTo(): http://jsfiddle.net/2akwx/1/

Comment: I notice that you have three divs for container, overlay, and links. Is it necessary to have the container div? What is it's function if it doesn't really have any properties associated with it? ... well other than positioning properties.

Comment: Actually the positioning properties are the only reason that it is there. The `position: absolute` on the child classes will relate to the parent div, so you can move the parent div wherever you want. You need the position styles to get the child elements to overlay each other (take them off and see what happens).

Answer (score 0):

You are linking it up with the div not the actual anchor element.

```
$("#columnRight a,#columnRight2 a,#columnRight3 a,#columnRight4 a").hover(function() {
     // etc
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CWabK/)

Also side note: You want the link to be -invisible- beforehand?? How would anyone know when / how to hover over it!

Comment: Good point about not being able to see the link. I can see how that would be confusing. Basically the image is so large that it would be unlikely to avoid hovering over it at some point and triggering the hover event revealing the underlying text.